# thingsboard navigation to other dashboard states

Tags: navigation, state, dashboard, custom-action, thingsboard

Does anyone know how to navigate to other dashboard states for asset instead of devices? As I would like to navigate to other dashboard states for the different levels. 
I hope someone is able to help me with this issue of mine that I have tried solving for quite some time. Below will be the screenshots of the different levels for my dashboard
and also the code I have put in my custom action.

I have tried many various ways and one of them is the one below:

```
var $injector = widgetContext.$scope.$injector;

$injector.get('assetService').getAsset(entityId.id).then

(function(asset) {

    if(asset.getName == 'LEVEL 5') {
        openDashboardState('building_level_view');
    } else if(asset.getName == 'LEVEL 6') {
        openDashboardState('building_level_lab_view');
    } else {
        openDashboardState('building_view');
    }
});

function openDashboardState(StateId) {
    var params = {
        entityId: entityId,
        entityName: entityName
    };

    widgetContext.stateController.openState(StateId, params, false);
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
We have found a solution where we need to group all the asset type in one asset group.

Answer (score 1):

In case you still have the problem try `asset.name`  instead of `asset.getName`.

It worked for me (on demo platform)